# Reading .plist from online

Tags: uitableview, plist, nsurlconnection

I've followed this tutorial: http://www.iphonedevcentral.com/hello-uitableview/

I've got it working great and all, but I can't quite figure out how to make it work by accessing the plist they've included, online.

Their plist is located here: http://www.iphonedevcentral.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/TestData.plist

And the source code for their tutorial is here: http://www.iphonedevcentral.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/MyDVDLibrary01.zip

Answer (score 0):

For what i can see, the call to the file on that exercise refer to an internal resource:

```
libraryContent = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                                                              pathForResource:libraryPlist ofType:@"plist"]];
```

In order to have tis working you need to download the TestData.plist file from the server and copy it in your Xcode project. If you want to load the file from the server you have to change those lines with something like this:

```
libraryContent = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.iphonedevcentral.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/TestData.plist"]];
```